# ActiveX и C#

Tags: activex, c#

Расскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом создать элемент ActiveX на C#. Поиски в интернете выдают только VB и C++. Меня конкретно интересует вид проекта в C#. И если у кого есть ссылки на книги по сабжу, прошу скинуть.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Простейший пример ActiveX на C#.

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Example 
{

    public interface Greetings
    {
        string Greeting();
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class Sample : Greetings
    {
        public string Greeting()
        {
            return "Hello, World!";
        }
    }
}
```

Сборка:

> `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /t:library example.cs`

Регистрация в системе (от администратора):

> `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe example.dll /tlb /codebase`

Тестовая страница:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script language="javascript">
    <!-- Загрузить объект ActiveX -->
    var z = new ActiveXObject("Example.Sample");

    <!-- Вызвать метод -->
    alert(z.Greeting());
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Более подробная документация:

- [Пошаговое руководство по созданию ActiveX на C#](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSActiveX-c3f43e7d) (на английском).
- [Предоставление COM-клиентам доступа к компонентам .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zsfww439(v=VS.100).aspx) (на русском).

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идет о простом компоненте повторного использования - то все сказано в первом ответе. Если же речь идет об интерфейсном элементе - то все не так просто. C# в чистом виде не дает такой возможности. Но можно сделать контрол на C#, а потом сделать для него обертку на С++ с использованием MFC. В MFC есть класс [CWinFormsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s15zk9k4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), оборачивающий WinForms контролы в CWnd. Далее нужно, используя возможности WinForms, сделать обычный контрол на C#, назовем его, к примеру MyLib.MyControl. Далее, создать ActiveX MFC проект, в свойствах проекта включить  поддержку CLR и добавить ссылку на сборку с контролом. В заголовочном файле ActiveX добавить член

```
CWinFormsControl<MyLib::MyControl>  m_myControl;
```

и вставить/расширить обработчики событий в ActiveX (как это сделать - см. доку по MFC):

```
int MyActiveX::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (COleControl::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    m_myControl.CreateManagedControl(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0,0,0,0), this, 0);
    m_myControl.ModifyStyleEx(0, WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT);

    return 0;
}

void MyActiveX::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    COleControl::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    if (::IsWindow(m_myControl.m_hWnd))
        m_myControl.MoveWindow(0, 0, cx, cy);
}
```

Полученный в результате сборки ActiveX будет выглядеть как контрол, сделанный на C#. Важно - управляемая сборка, которая содержит контрол, должна либо лежать в GAC, либо рядом с Exe-файлом, использующим ActiveX.

Comment: Хотелось бы действительно подробно узнать об этом, так как я собираюсь использовать контрол в 1с. К тому же предыдущий пример не компилируется в CLR и не собирается почему то в командной строке! ОС - Вин 7

Comment: Впрочем, я посмотрел ссылку на пошаговую инструкцию из предыдущего примера - выглядит так, что тот вариант более простой для использования и позволяет весь контрол поместить в один проект, а не размазывать по двум.

Comment: А можно объяснить мне, непонятливому, каким образом обработать событие - Click() в программу - контейнер для контрола? Мне необходимо чтобы контрол отловил событие - нажание на него и передал выполнение в 1С, а уже 1С обработала это событие! Естественно мне это необходимо только со стороны ActiveX контрола

Comment: Это уже вопрос интеграции контрола с 1С. Видимо, следует добавить контролу событие, соответствующее клику, при щелчке мыши его сгенерировать, а в 1С его поймать и обработать

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать Ireflect для обертки объектов .Net а так же динамический компиляцию обертки Net событий в COM. Например

Динамическая компиляция класса обертки для использования .Net событий в 1С через ДобавитьОбработчик или ОбработкаВнешнегоСобытия, а так же генерация модулей на C# и 1С для подключения к событиям. Использование DynamicMethod и ILGenerator. Представлены примеры на использовании событий System.IO.FileSystemWatcher (Ожидает уведомления файловой системы об изменениях и инициирует события при изменениях каталога или файла в каталоге.) и SerialPort (обработка сканера штрих кода подключенного к COM порту). Обертка позволяет использовать сборки .Net только на языке 1С.

Как то раз пришлось написать интеграцию 1С с WhatsApp. А там порядка 30 событий.
В ручную это делать было муторно как для обертки событий, так и для использования их в 1С.
Не поленился и написал кодогенератор.
Рассмотрим генерацию кода на примере System.IO.FileSystemWatcher

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[Guid("6821a54a-19a2-4e66-85d9-e65396958080")]
public interface IВрапперДляSystem_IO_FileSystemWatcher
{

    [DispId(0x00000001)]
    void ОшибкаСобытия(String событие, object value, object исключение);
    [DispId(0x00000002)]
    void Changed(object value);
    [DispId(0x00000003)]
    void Created(object value);
    [DispId(0x00000004)]
    void Deleted(object value);
    [DispId(0x00000005)]
    void Error(object value);
    [DispId(0x00000006)]
    void Renamed(object value);
    [DispId(0x00000007)]
    void Disposed(object value);

}


[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[Guid("c3919804-ff5f-4d2a-a773-5067a1e051e1")]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IВрапперДляSystem_IO_FileSystemWatcher))]
public class ВрапперДляSystem_IO_FileSystemWatcher
{

    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void Событие_Delgate();
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void СобытиеСПараметром_Delgate(object value);
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void СобытиеСПараметрами_Delgate(String событие, object value, object исключение);

    public System.IO.FileSystemWatcher РеальныйОбъект;
    dynamic AutoWrap;
    private SynchronizationContext Sc;
    public event СобытиеСПараметрами_Delgate ОшибкаСобытия;
    public Exception ПоследняяОшибка;
    public event СобытиеСПараметром_Delgate Changed;
    public event СобытиеСПараметром_Delgate Created;
    public event СобытиеСПараметром_Delgate Deleted;
    public event СобытиеСПараметром_Delgate Error;
    public event СобытиеСПараметром_Delgate Renamed;
    public event СобытиеСПараметром_Delgate Disposed;

    private Object thisLock = new Object();


    void ОтослатьСобытие(Событие_Delgate Событие, string ИмяСобытия)
    {


        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (Событие != null) //Событие();
            {
                lock (thisLock)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        Sc.Send(d => Событие(), null);
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            Sc.Send(d => ОшибкаСобытия(ИмяСобытия, null, AutoWrap.ОбернутьОбъект(ex)), null);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void ОтослатьСобытиеСПараметром(СобытиеСПараметром_Delgate Событие, object value, string ИмяСобытия)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {


            if (Событие != null) //Событие();
            {
                lock (thisLock)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Sc.Send(d => Событие(AutoWrap.ОбернутьОбъект(value)), null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            Sc.Send(d => ОшибкаСобытия(ИмяСобытия, AutoWrap.ОбернутьОбъект(value), AutoWrap.ОбернутьОбъект(ex)), null);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });


    }
    public ВрапперДляSystem_IO_FileSystemWatcher(object AutoWrap, System.IO.FileSystemWatcher РеальныйОбъект)
    {

        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null)
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());

        Sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;


        this.РеальныйОбъект = РеальныйОбъект;
        this.AutoWrap = AutoWrap;
        РеальныйОбъект.Changed += (sender, e) =>
        {

            ОтослатьСобытиеСПараметром(Changed, new { sender = sender, e = e }, "Changed");
        };

        РеальныйОбъект.Created += (sender, e) =>
        {

            ОтослатьСобытиеСПараметром(Created, new { sender = sender, e = e }, "Created");
        };

        РеальныйОбъект.Deleted += (sender, e) =>
        {

            ОтослатьСобытиеСПараметром(Deleted, new { sender = sender, e = e }, "Deleted");
        };

        РеальныйОбъект.Error += (sender, e) =>
        {

            ОтослатьСобытиеСПараметром(Error, new { sender = sender, e = e }, "Error");
        };

        РеальныйОбъект.Renamed += (sender, e) =>
        {

            ОтослатьСобытиеСПараметром(Renamed, new { sender = sender, e = e }, "Renamed");
        };

        РеальныйОбъект.Disposed += (sender, e) =>
        {

            ОтослатьСобытиеСПараметром(Disposed, new { sender = sender, e = e }, "Disposed");
        };


    }

    public static object СоздатьОбъект(object AutoWrap, System.IO.FileSystemWatcher РеальныйОбъект)
    {

        return new ВрапперДляSystem_IO_FileSystemWatcher(AutoWrap, РеальныйОбъект);
    }
}
```

Более подробно можно посмотреть здесь http://infostart.ru/public/417830/

Сам компилятор выглядит так

```
public class КомВраперДляСобытий<T>
        {
        private static MethodInfo cоздательОбертки = null;
        private static MethodInfo cоздательОбертки77 = null;

       static CompilerResults СкомпилироватьОбертку(string строкаКласса,string ИмяКласса)
        {


            bool ЭтоСборкаГак = typeof(T).Assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache;
            string Путь = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(T).Assembly.Location);



            string OutputAssembly = Path.Combine(Путь, ИмяКласса) + ".dll";


            var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            var parameters = new CompilerParameters();

            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(AutoWrap).Assembly.Location);

            if (!ЭтоСборкаГак)
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(T).Assembly.Location);
            else
            {
                string ИмяСборки = typeof(T).Assembly.ManifestModule.Name;
                if (parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.IndexOf(ИмяСборки) == -1)
                    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(ИмяСборки);


            }

            if (ЭтоСборкаГак)
                parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            else
            { //  parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
                parameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
                parameters.OutputAssembly = OutputAssembly;
            }

            parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
            parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true;

            var res = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, строкаКласса);
            return res;
        }
        public static MethodInfo СоздательОбертки { get {
                if (cоздательОбертки==null)
                {
                    Type типРеальногоОбъекта = typeof(T);
                    string ТипСтрРеальногоОбъекта = типРеальногоОбъекта.FullName;
                    var ИмяКласса = "ВрапперДля" + ТипСтрРеальногоОбъекта.Replace(".", "_").Replace("+", "_");
                   string  строкаКласса = ДляСозданияМодуляВрапера.СоздатьОписания(типРеальногоОбъекта);
                    var res = СкомпилироватьОбертку(строкаКласса,ИмяКласса);

                    Type тип = res.CompiledAssembly.GetType(ИмяКласса);
                    MethodInfo mi = тип.GetMethod("СоздатьОбъект", new Type[]{typeof(object),типРеальногоОбъекта });

                    cоздательОбертки = mi;
                }

                return cоздательОбертки;
            } }

        public static MethodInfo СоздательОбертки77
        {
            get
            {
                if (cоздательОбертки77 == null)
                {
                    Type типРеальногоОбъекта = typeof(T);
                    string ТипСтрРеальногоОбъекта = типРеальногоОбъекта.FullName;
                    var ИмяКласса = "ВрапперДля" + ТипСтрРеальногоОбъекта.Replace(".", "_").Replace("+", "_")+"77";
                    string строкаКласса = ДляСозданияМодуляВрапера.СоздатьОписания77(типРеальногоОбъекта);
                    var res = СкомпилироватьОбертку(строкаКласса, ИмяКласса);

                    Type тип = res.CompiledAssembly.GetType(ИмяКласса);
                    MethodInfo mi = тип.GetMethod("СоздатьОбъект", new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(object), типРеальногоОбъекта });

                    cоздательОбертки77 = mi;
                }

                return cоздательОбертки77;
            }
        }
```

Так, что бы лишний раз не компилировать, закэшируем результат компиляции через свойство дженерик класса. Реализацию этого класса Net будет создавать при первом обращении, а статические поля будем заполнять компиляцией динамически создаваемого модуля на C# только раз для каждого типа.
Так для GAC сборок можно компилировать сборку в памяти. Для не гаковских сборок нужно указывать путь, где лежит сборка оборачиваемого типа.

Вызов из 1С происходит с помощью 2 методов СоздатьОберткуДляСобытий или СоздатьОберткуДляСобытий77

```
MethodInfo ПолучитьMethodInfoОберткиСобытий(string ИмяСвойства, object РеальныйОбъект)
        {

//      получаем дженерик тип КомВраперДляСобытий<> и указывем тип 

            Type тип = РеальныйОбъект.GetType();
            Type genType = typeof(КомВраперДляСобытий<>);
            Type constructed = genType.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { тип });

            // Now находим свойство и получаем его значение
            PropertyInfo pi = constructed.GetProperty(ИмяСвойства);
            MethodInfo функция = (MethodInfo)pi.GetValue(null, null);
            return функция;

        }
        public object СоздатьОберткуДляСобытий(object объект)
        {

            object РеальныйОбъект = AutoWrap.ПолучитьРеальныйОбъект(объект);
            var функция = ПолучитьMethodInfoОберткиСобытий("СоздательОбертки", РеальныйОбъект);
            object обертка = функция.Invoke(null,new object[] { this,РеальныйОбъект });
// Возвращаем реальный объект, так как он является COM объектом
            return обертка;

        }
        public object СоздатьОберткуДляСобытий77(object объект, object ГлобальныйКонтекст)
        {

            object РеальныйОбъект = AutoWrap.ПолучитьРеальныйОбъект(объект);
            var функция = ПолучитьMethodInfoОберткиСобытий("СоздательОбертки77", РеальныйОбъект);
            object обертка = функция.Invoke(null, new object[] {ГлобальныйКонтекст,РеальныйОбъект });
// Оборачиваем обертку событий в AutoWrap для использования в 1С как объекта автоматизации
            return AutoWrap.ОбернутьОбъект(обертка);

        }
```